# Failed to extract system.img Android

Tags: android, extract, firmware

I have a system.img file which seems to be an Android image. The image is recent (2022).

I can't extract it with sim2img or parsex .

```
simg2img system.img  system.img.raw
Invalid sparse file format at header magic
Failed to read sparse file

kpartx -av system.img
return nothing, no line

fdisk -lu system.img 
Disk system.img: 14,57 MiB, 15278080 bytes, 29840 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
```

When I look the file in a hex editor, I see Android referenced. I have others reason to think it's Android.

[The file.](http://media.canicompet.com/canicompet/system.img)

Someone would have an idea for me ?

Thank you